# Cannot use array from other method in c#

Tags: arrays, indexing, methods, get, speech

I am trying to create a voice assistant and I'm having issues trying to find the index of my grammar Choices array from a different method. How can I access "list" from the method "rec_SpeechRecognized". I am fairly new to programming so please be kind.

```
{
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int findIndex<T>(this T[] list, T r)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(list, r);
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    public Choices list = new Choices();
    public string[] answerArray = { "hello", "I sure am", "who whould have known" };  
    public Form1()
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        list.Add(new string[] { "hello", "are you serious?", "there's gotta be something wrong with you" });
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));
        try
        {
            rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
            rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
            rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch { return; }
        s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
        s.Speak("Hello, my name is magma!");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void say(String h)
    {
        s.Speak(h);
    }
    private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        String r = e.Result.Text;
        int answer = list.findIndex(r);
            if (list.Contains(r))
            {
            say(answerArray[answer]);
            }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify what Choices is supposed to be (what class/interface it derives from)? Based on methods use I would say a derivation of List<T> (or something like that) but that is not an array so your extension method would have problem with that. You can try make your extension method to accept IList<T> instead of T[] and use IndexOf from there (IList is interface that is implemented by both list and array)

Comment: Choices is the grammar that the program can understand when I speak to it. I will try your suggestion later this evening ans see if I can make it work. But you have given me some good advice for sure. Thanks!